# Nonflammable flight gas

Tags: flight, gas

What would be a lighter-than-air gas that is also not flammable, and would be fairly easy to produce in a modern-style world?

Comment: What's wrong with helium?

Comment: It's too hard to get.

Comment: Hard to get? Helium is a by-product of oil and gas extraction. It costs about 300 US dollars for a million standard cubic feet. (It used to be cheaper because the USA was selling off a mind-bogglingly huge century old strategic reserve, which they had put together at the beginning of the 20th century when they thought that airships would be very important in wars... That useless stash is gone now.)

Comment: Yes, but it is incredibly hard to get more, new helium.

Comment: Helium is a by-product of oil and natural gas extraction... Where do you think the US Bureau of Land Management got their gigantic stash?

Comment: Oh. Ok. Didn't know that. But still, oil is a finite resource.

Comment: All atoms of all elements are present in a finite amount on Earth. Did you want a gas that can be conjured by magic?

Comment: No, not quite. I meant that I wanted a gas that could be made easily from other forms on the planet.

Comment: I believe you had similar problem to me - I wanted hard to get something as good or better than hydrogen, and well, after thinking of changing physics to allow existence of such thing, i Just let it go and learnt to love the helium. It's really not that bad, and you can get more lift out of it by heating it

Comment: Fun fact: If we call centrifugal force an imaginary byproduct of centripetal acceleration then Hydrostatic lift is just gravity seen from an odd angle.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Mranderson How could you change physics to allow it, as in what way were you thinking?

Comment: @ILoveAllGolems tbh I just thought about making new exotic particles haha. It wasn't a well thought idea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. **Hot air.**   Cheap, readily available, nonflammable.  The hotter, the liftier.  You can replenish your supply anywhere you can breathe.
2. **Gaseous water.**  Cheap, readily available, nonflammable.  The hotter, the liftier.  You can replenish your supply a lot of places.  You will need a container that can withstand the steam.
3. **Anhydrous ammonia**.  Dark horse candidate and never used as a lift gas   to my knowledge.  But definitely lighter than air and boiling at -33 C, a gas at most earthly temperatures.  Caustic.  Technically flammable but only at high oxygen levels so no explosion risk.  Ammonia can be synthesized from N2.

Comment: Those were so blindingly obvious I didn't even think about them. Thanks!

Comment: All I can think about are blindingly obvious things, so I have an advantage there.

Comment: Also, I looked up the material safety data sheet for anhydrous ammonia. [https://msds.orica.com/pdf/shess-en-cds-010-000031098301.pdf](https://msds.orica.com/pdf/shess-en-cds-010-000031098301.pdf). Nasty.

Comment: Ammonia definitely blinding ;-)

Comment: Yes it is indeed.

Answer (score 4):

If you can produce a thin rigid shell for your airship out of carbon or silicon, then you use the atmosphere itself as your lift gas by creating a vacuum inside the shell.  Neal Stephenson’s Diamond Age used this principle to make light evacuated cells that were used for tiny drones and giant airships.

Comment: That is incredibly cool, thanks!